# Compiler doesn't find jar: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist

Tags: java, jar, ejb, soa, jdeveloper

I want to deploy an EJB but when compiling I get the following error

```
Error(9,24):  package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
Error(11,23):  package javax.ws.rs.ext does not exist
```

But I have the jars in the project Libraries and Classpath.

I'm using Jdeveloper.

What is causing this error?

Comment: You should show the line the compiler complains about and name the jar you use. Perhaps it is even a good idea to show your setup of project libraries and classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Maven...

I think you should include the Java EE dependencies in your POM.

Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```